# Only event onclick work with canva and easeIJS

Tags: events, canvas, easeljs

I'm using canvas and the framework easeIJS for build a isometric map.

So, I have a function for add a tile on my map :

```
p.addTile = function ( $tile, $x, $y, $z )
{
        $tile.posX = $x;
        $tile.posY = $y;
        $tile.posZ = $z;
        $tile.map = this;

        this.tiles.push ( $tile );
        this.addChild ( $tile.content );

        this.update ();

        $tile.content.onClick = function ()
        {
                this.tile.map.movePlayer ( this.tile.posX, this.tile.posY );
        };
};
```

This function works perfectly.
You can an event, onclick. Here, when I click on a tile, the function `movePlayer()` does its job, so no problem.

But when I try to add an other event, like onMouseOver, on my tile, it doesn't work..

Do you have any ideas? I tried, for example :

```
$tile.content.OnMouseOver = function ()
        {
                alert('ok');
        };
```

But I can't see the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok, i just forget to enabled mouseOver...

```
stage.enableMouseOver(20);
```